# Problema con React o npm! Pantalla en blanco!

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Al ejecutar npm start no da error alguno pero en el navegador se ve totalmente en blanco y sale este error en la consola. [image: Captura de pantalla de la consola]

Aquí esta el archivo
**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import 'tachyons';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

y aquí el correspondiente **package.json**

```javascript
{
  "name": "freakadvisor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.7.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Tengo dos vulnerabilidades al ejecutar:
`npm audit`
[image: captura de pantalla de npm audit]

Tiene esto algo que ver?? No consigo identificar el problema, estoy haciendo varios ejercicios siguiendo las instrucciones paso a paso y me pasa lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu archivo de webpack? ¿Cuál es tu código index.js?

Comment: ¿puedes indicar los pasos que seguiste?

Answer (score 0):

## Opción 1

Primeramente ejecuta

```
npm install
```

Luego intenta nuevamente

```
npm start
```

## Opción 2

Si lo anterior no funciona intenta con

```
npm update react react-dom
```

Luego intenta nuevamente

```
npm start
```

Comment: Nada, no actualiza nada y sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje en consola.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el contenido del package.json y todo lo que tenga en index.js